# Error while running deepmimic example in pybullet with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, bullet

While running pybullet deep_mimic example which uses tensorflow and OpenAI gym and baseline packages, i ran into this error. The window appeared for a second with the bot and then crashed. I am running it with python 3.8 and tensorflow 2.3.1. I dont have an Nvidia card but that doesnt seem to be a problem?

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable 
agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. 

Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph)
         [[{{node agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2}}]]
.
.
.
Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2:
 agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph (defined at Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages
\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py:63)
```

code at tf_normalizer.py:63:

```
44:   def unnormalize_tf(self, norm_x):
45:     x = norm_x * self.std_tf + self.mean_tf
46:     return x
47: 
48:   def _build_resource_tf(self):
49:     self.count_tf = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.int32,
50:                                     name='count',
51:                                     initializer=np.array([self.count], dtype=np.int32),
52:                                     trainable=False)
53:     self.mean_tf = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32,
54:                                    name='mean',
55:                                    initializer=self.mean.astype(np.float32),
56:                                    trainable=False)
57:     self.std_tf = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32,
58:                                   name='std',
59:                                   initializer=self.std.astype(np.float32),
60:                                   trainable=False)
61: 
62:     self.count_ph = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.int32, name='count_ph', shape=[1])
63:     self.mean_ph = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='mean_ph', shape=self.mean.shape)
64:     self.std_ph = tf.get_variable(dtype=tf.float32, name='std_ph', shape=self.std.shape)
65:
```

The Complete output:

```
(pyml) PS C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs> python -m pybullet_envs.deep_mimic.testrl --arg_file run_humanoid3d_backflip_args.txt
parentdir= C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages
2020-10-06 02:32:20.161043: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-10-06 02:32:20.165704: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
pybullet build time: Oct  6 2020 02:07:04
run_humanoid3d_backflip_args.txt
enable_draw= True
Initialization strategy: InitializationStrategy.RANDOM
starting thread 0
started testThreads thread 0 with threadHandle 00000000000006F4
argc=2
argv[0] = --unused
argv[1] = --start_demo_name=Physics Server
ExampleBrowserThreadFunc started
Version = 4.6.13543 Compatibility Profile Context 25.20.15002.58
Vendor = ATI Technologies Inc.
Renderer = Radeon RX Vega M GH Graphics
b3Printf: Selected demo: Physics Server
starting thread 0
started MotionThreads thread 0 with threadHandle 0000000000002158
MotionThreadFunc thread started
motion_file= data/motions/humanoid3d_backflip.txt
LOADING humanoid!
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: chest
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: neck
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_hip
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_ankle
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_shoulder
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_hip
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_ankle
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_shoulder
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: chest
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: neck
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_hip
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_ankle
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: right_shoulder
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_hip
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_ankle
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: urdfdom: no axis elemement for Joint, defaulting to (1,0,0) axis
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/Importers/ImportURDFDemo/BulletUrdfImporter.cpp,126]:

b3Printf: left_shoulder
num_agents= 1

Num Agents: 1
len(agent_files)= 1
Agent 0: data/agents/ct_agent_humanoid_ppo.txt
2020-10-06 02:32:22.265256: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-10-06 02:32:22.269722: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:312] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-10-06 02:32:22.272419: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-22JP51K
2020-10-06 02:32:22.276323: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-22JP51K
2020-10-06 02:32:22.281654: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-06 02:32:22.297342: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x24f9154db50 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-06 02:32:22.303706: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
state_offset= [ 0.5 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.  -0.
 -0. ]
state_scale= [0.5 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1365, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1349, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1441, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph)
         [[{{node agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\testrl.py", line 97, in <module>
    world = build_world(args, True)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\testrl.py", line 68, in build_world
    world = RLWorld(env, arg_parser)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.build_agents()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 75, in build_agents
    curr_agent = self._build_agent(i, curr_file)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 141, in _build_agent
    agent = AgentBuilder.build_agent(self, id, agent_file)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\agent_builder.py", line 18, in build_agent
    agent = PPOAgent(world, id, json_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\ppo_agent.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\pg_agent.py", line 43, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_agent.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_agent.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._build_normalizers()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\pg_agent.py", line 98, in _build_normalizers
    super()._build_normalizers()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_agent.py", line 106, in _build_normalizers
    self.s_norm.set_mean_std(-self.world.env.build_state_offset(self.id),
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py", line 36, in set_mean_std
    self._update_resource_tf()
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py", line 76, in _update_resource_tf
    self.sess.run(self._update_op, feed_dict=feed)
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 957, in run
    result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1180, in _run
    results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1358, in _do_run
    return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1384, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph)
         [[node agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2 (defined at Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py:67) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2:
 agent/resource/s_norm/mean_ph (defined at Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py:63)

Original stack trace for 'agent/resource/s_norm/ReadVariableOp_2':
  File "Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\testrl.py", line 97, in <module>
    world = build_world(args, True)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\testrl.py", line 68, in build_world
    world = RLWorld(env, arg_parser)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.build_agents()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 75, in build_agents
    curr_agent = self._build_agent(i, curr_file)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_world.py", line 141, in _build_agent
    agent = AgentBuilder.build_agent(self, id, agent_file)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\agent_builder.py", line 18, in build_agent
    agent = PPOAgent(world, id, json_data)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\ppo_agent.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\pg_agent.py", line 43, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_agent.py", line 22, in __init__
    super().__init__(world, id, json_data)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\rl_agent.py", line 93, in __init__
    self._build_normalizers()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\pg_agent.py", line 98, in _build_normalizers
    super()._build_normalizers()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_agent.py", line 100, in _build_normalizers
    self.s_norm = TFNormalizer(self.sess, 's_norm', self.get_state_size(),
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py", line 18, in __init__
    self._build_resource_tf()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\pybullet_envs\deep_mimic\learning\tf_normalizer.py", line 67, in _build_resource_tf
    self.mean_tf.assign(self.mean_ph), self.std_tf.assign(self.std_ph))
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 857, in assign
    value_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=self.dtype)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1499, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1909, in _dense_var_to_tensor
    return var._dense_var_to_tensor(dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 1326, in _dense_var_to_tensor
    return self.value()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 555, in value
    return self._read_variable_op()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 657, in _read_variable_op
    result = read_and_set_handle()
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 647, in read_and_set_handle
    result = gen_resource_variable_ops.read_variable_op(self._handle,
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_resource_variable_ops.py", line 490, in read_variable_op
    _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 742, in _apply_op_helper
    op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3477, in _create_op_internal
    ret = Operation(
  File "Users\user\Downloads\lab\python\venvs\pyml\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1949, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

numActiveThreads = 0
stopping threads
Thread with taskId 0 with handle 0000000000002158 exiting
Thread TERMINATED
finished
numActiveThreads = 0
btShutDownExampleBrowser stopping threads
Thread with taskId 0 with handle 00000000000006F4 exiting
Thread TERMINATED
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So running it on tensorflow 1.13 and python 3.7 worked.